# Undefined symbols for architecture i386 linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: clang, linker-errors, appdelegate, i386, invocation

I have looked through other questions that had similar issues, but I still can't figure out what is wrong. This is my first app and the other answers didn't make much sense. I keep getting the same error:

```
Ld /Users/brandonpayne/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FordyceSchools-gcczvpeftaotknfzpktdnjoqzncf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FordyceSchools.app/FordyceSchools normal i386
cd /Users/brandonpayne/Desktop/FordyceSchools
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk -L/Users/brandonpayne/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FordyceSchools-gcczvpeftaotknfzpktdnjoqzncf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/brandonpayne/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FordyceSchools-gcczvpeftaotknfzpktdnjoqzncf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/brandonpayne/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FordyceSchools-gcczvpeftaotknfzpktdnjoqzncf/Build/Intermediates/FordyceSchools.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FordyceSchools.build/Objects-normal/i386/FordyceSchools.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50100 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/brandonpayne/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FordyceSchools-gcczvpeftaotknfzpktdnjoqzncf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FordyceSchools.app/FordyceSchools
```

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I can't find in my code where the error is. Please help.